# Java Breaking for loop when counter reaches certain point

Tags: java, for-loop, counter, break

I'm a beginner in Java so please don't be too harsh on me. I tried to find a solution to the problem but didn't manage so far. Long story short, I want to make to make a program that will add numbers 1-1000, and adding should stop once the sum reaches 3000. Also, I should print the number where it stopped (the last value of my "i" before the loop stopped for break). This is my attempt, but wouldn't work:

```
public class JavaApplication2018 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        {
          sum = sum + i;  
          if (sum == 3000)
             {
          System.out.println(i);
          break;
          }
        }

    System.out.println(sum);  

    }  


}
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: 3000 isn't a number in the series `1 + 2 + 3 + ...`. 2926 is; 3003 is.

Comment: It should be **if (sum >= 3000)**

Comment: I tried to run it, no, it doesn't work.

Comment: TheOni but I want it to stop at or before 3000?

Comment: Since you'll not need `i` to reach anywhere near 1000 before the sum exceeds 3000 (the final `i` value will be near sqrt(2 * 3000), which in turn is about 77), you could could make `sum < 3000` the loop condition.  In that case, move the declaration of `i` outside the loop so that you can print its (final) value after the loop exits.

Comment: @AndyTurner Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi perhaps you can do 2 small modifications:

1. add the line below before the if, so you can see what is happening

System.out.println("i =" + i + "; sum = "  + sum);

2. change the if to: if (sum > 3000)

So you can see:

```
i =75; sum = 2850
i =76; sum = 2926
i =77; sum = 3003
```

Answer (score 3):

If you change a bit your program, you'll see that there is no possibility to execute the code included in this part:

```
if (sum == 3000) {
    System.out.println(i);
    break;
}
```

, because there is no possibility that the `sum` of these numbers can be **equal to** 3000. You can check it by adding a line printing actual sum after each iteration:

```
public class JavaApplication2018 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            sum = sum + i;
            System.out.println(sum); // this line is added just to print actual sum value
            if (sum >= 3000) { // you need to change this operator from ">" to ">=" to make the code inside the if statement execute
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Numbers printed:

```
...
2850
2926
3003
```

If you want your loop to break **before** the iteration that would cause exceeding 3000, then you can change your if statement to:

```
if ((sum + i + 1) > 3000) {
    System.out.println(i);
    break;
}
```

Output is now:

```
76
2926
```

Comment: @BellaCarol I added new paragraph to cover a case that you want to break a loop when next iteration would exceed 3000. If you find my answer helpful you can upvote it and if you consider my answer as a best one, you might also want to tick it as the accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to upvote but can't for some reason. Maybe I need to spend more time here to be able to cast votes, which I will. Thank you, I spent so much time wondering what might be wrong about my code..

Comment: @BellaCarol Yeah, there are 15 points of reputation needed to upvote here actually. Glad that I could help you anyway :-)

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment cause i don't have enough reputation, but if you want it to stop just before 3000,

```
public class JavaApplication2018 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
        {
          sum = sum + i;  
          if (sum >= 3000)
             {
          sum=sum-i;
          System.out.println(i-1);
          break;
          }
        }

    System.out.println(sum);  

    }  


}
```

when you get to 3003, just get sum=3003- i (the last number in the series before 3003) and i=i-1 :)

Good luck on studying Java

Comment: Thank you! I can't upvote either but am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000 && sum <= 3001; i++)
    {
      sum = sum + i;  
      if (sum == 3000)
      {
         System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
System.out.println(sum);  
}
```